# Creating remember me functionality in login page in android

Tags: android

I am able to create remember me functionality in my login page, when i restart my app the username and password field are already filled but i have to click on the login button to get to another activity.

How to code if i want to directly load another activity if remember me checkbox is true rather than clicking on the login button again when i again load my application.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);  
        et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        register = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.register);
        saveLoginCheckBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.remember);
        loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        loginPrefsEditor = loginPreferences.edit();

        saveLogin = loginPreferences.getBoolean("saveLogin", false);
        if (saveLogin == true) {
            et.setText(loginPreferences.getString("username", ""));
            pass.setText(loginPreferences.getString("password", ""));
            saveLoginCheckBox.setChecked(true);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", 
                        "Validating user...", true);
                 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(et.getWindowToken(), 0);

                            username = et.getText().toString();
                            password = pass.getText().toString();

                            if (saveLoginCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                                loginPrefsEditor.putBoolean("saveLogin", true);
                                loginPrefsEditor.putString("username", username);
                                loginPrefsEditor.putString("password", password);
                                loginPrefsEditor.commit();


                            } else {
                                loginPrefsEditor.clear();
                                loginPrefsEditor.commit();

                            }

                          login();

                        }
                      }).start();               
            }
        });

}
}
```

note : i want something like we have on facebook . After entering username, password and check the remember me checkbox if i open the facebook page again then my homepage will appear rather than the welcome screen where i have to just click on login button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
if (saveLogin == true) {

Intent i = new Intent(this, ClassName.class);
startActivity(i);
finish()
}
```

Put this in your onCreate(), so when your login activity starts, it will check the saveLogin status, if its true, it will send to another activity, else it will stay on login page.

Answer (score 0):

AutoCompleteTextView seems right thing to use. when you start typing it will search /database/file/array for entered information. You'll have to implement onListItemClickedlistener for it.